# HDD Failure, SATA failure or both?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, sata

After 3 years running a DELL T110 server with Linux Debian and ProxMox version 2.6.32 I started getting the following messages (Running `dmesg` shows tons of these messages):

```
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x10 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:20:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x7f SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x40 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:30:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x3 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:08:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 41/40:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: qc timeout (cmd 0x2f)
ata4: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
ata4.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x3 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 32768 in
         res 40/00:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata4.00: cmd 60/80:08:d0:84:c0/00:00:41:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 65536 in
         res 40/00:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
ata4: hard resetting link
ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:b0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:01:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:02:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:04:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:05:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:b0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:01:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:04:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:05:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata4.00: cmd 25/00:40:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 32768 in
         res 51/40:00:c0:39:29/00:00:cc:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata4.00: error: { UNC }
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
        cc 29 39 c0 
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 cc 29 39 c0 00 00 40 00
ata4: EH complete
```

I have 4 disks on the server, and the system is running very slow in some VM´s for some time.

Is that a interface related problem, a disk end-of-life problem or both. Helop appreciated to :

a) Diagnose if it is an interface problem, a disk problem, both or something different than that.
b) Identify wich disk/interface shall be repaired.
c) Solving the issue.

Comment: See this...http://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous

Answer (score 0):

ata4 device is dying replace it NOW!!!  The hdd has bad sectors, and tried but failed to reallocate them.  This is probably because it used up all the spare sectors it had.  If the drive has consumed all spare sectors, its basically a time bomb waiting to go off and lose all your data.

Comment: Hdd or interface ? Wich hdd ?

Comment: All I know is its **/dev/sdd**.  you can use **df -h** from the command line to see what is mounted there.  **ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid**  If the uuid is stamped on the hdd this might help.  OR **hdparm -i /dev/sdd**  That should display the Model # and Serial #.

Comment: Could also be a connector issue? Wouldn't he want to run additional tests? Maybe smart so he could see pending and reallocated sector counts?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Physically connector errors are winning the 100 million jackpot rare.  He can check if he wants to, the way its stated makes it seem he hasn't opened it in 3 years and issue just started.  Unless he forgot to mention he dropped the computer or had an earthquake its not the connector.  I manage 250+ computers and have replaced them all several times, never had a connector error.  It is was unplugged or loose the BIOS wouldn't see the hdd.  The logs says **auto reallocate failed** there are no more spares.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  The drive is clearly on its death bed.  If they run Spinrite,mhdd, or etc here is what will happen.  Day 1.  5 hours left  Day 2 5 days left Day 3: 5 weeks left Day 4: 5 months Day 5:  Replace the hard drive and regret wasting 4 days.

Comment: No earthquakes, just some energy drop during heavy raining days - no ups.